# Comandos para atualizar Ubuntu apt-get update ou apt update sem get?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Na empresa recebemos a instrução de rodar os seguintes comandos toda manhã, mas o gerente de projetos atual não soube me responder o motivo e na pesquisa na internet não obtive uma boa resposta.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt upgrade
```

Outro detalhe que me chamou a atenção é que não tem uma sequencia para ser executados, vai a gosto do desenvolvedor.

A maquina é usada para desenvolver front-end mas as linhas que vão atualizando com os comandos não vejo nada de `npm`, `gulp`, `bower` ou `php`, que são os aplicativos que utilizamos, então qual o impacto de rodar esses comandos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O comando `apt-get update` atualiza a lista de pacotes e programas que podem ser instalados na máquina.

O comando `apt-get upgrade` atualiza o sistema e baixa e instala atualizações de pacotes e dos programas da máquina.

Não sei se é necessario rodar os 2 todo dia, uma vez que é pouco provavel que você possua programas que recebem atualizações todos os dias.

Comment: E o `apt update` e `apt upgrade` sem o uso do `get` seguem a mesma regra ou possui características diferentes?

Comment: Em minha maquina não vi diferença entre os 2 comandos ( com e sem o "get"),ambos executaram a mesma coisa.

Comment: Tem ainda o `sudo apt list --upgradable` para ver quem são esse pacotes que podem receber o upgrade

Answer (score 9):

o comando:

```
sudo apt update
```

É uma "atualização" do comando:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Não sendo mais necessário digitar "-get".

Você pode executar apenas o comando:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Assim não precisa esperar a resposta de um comando para executar o outro.

Comment: Eu sei que o `sudo apt-get update` atualiza a lista de pacotes e instala a versão mais recente. Posso estar errado, mas é o que entendi.

É seguro rodar o `apt-get  upgrade` sempre? Isso não irá quebrar alguma coisa? Principalmente para que trabalha com desenvolvimento, Apache, PHP, Laravel, etc...?